# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>') please hepl me

Tags: flutter, dart

> Blockquote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ1kd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njj8O.png)

I started researching json and faced such a problem. api from unsplash. Sorry if something is not clear, for the first time I leave my question here

```
`import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class OfficesList {
List<Office> offices;
OfficesList({this.offices});

factory OfficesList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
var officesJson = json['self'] as List;

List<Office> officesList = officesJson.map((i) => Office.fromJson(i));

return OfficesList(
  offices: officesList,
);
}
}

class Office {
final String username;
final String createdAt;
final String image;

Office({this.username, this.createdAt, this.image});

factory Office.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Office(
    username: json['updated_ad'] as String,
    createdAt: json['created_at'] as String,
    image: json['id'] as String);
}
}

Future<OfficesList> getOfficesList() async {
const url =
  'https://api.unsplash.com/photos? 
client_id=6L1WckRABJLdhkHch6iFN9qMhPaUVQKtyPuCw90wZdI';
final response = await http.get(url);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
return OfficesList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} else {
throw Exception('Error: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
}
}`
```

Comment: Can you give the response you received?

Comment: @Lapa Ny Aina Tanjona, Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a list of `Office`'s as response of your api call, but you are decoding it like you received one. Try this code to parse the api response:

```
List<Office> offices= new List<Office>();
List<dynamic> json = json.decode(response.body);
offices= json.map((i)=>Office.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Please let me know if that solves your problem.